# How to change the index of a certain section

Tags: sectioning, numbering, indexing

I'm having a problem with numbering sections in my project. I want to remove a certain ordinal index, and then replace it with another number. For instance, I have 10 sections, which are normally indexed from 1 to 10. But I want to change the index of 5th section to 6, and the rest sections are indexed from 7 to 11. May you help me with this ? My thanks so much.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3):

> I have 10 sections, which are normally indexed from 1 to 10. But I want to change the index of [the] 5th section to 6, and the [remaining] sections are indexed from 7 to 11.

For this use case, I suggest you insert the instruction

```
\stepcounter{section}
```

immediately ahead of the `\section` directive that would be numbered "5" by default -- and which you want to be numbered "6" instead.

Comment: I inserted this code \setcounter{section}{5} in front of the code \section, and it also changed my index to 6. Is there the difference between that and your code ?

Comment: @PermQi - There's obviously a difference between `\stepcounter{section}` and `\setcounter{section}{5}`, so I'm not sure I understand why you're asking this question. Now, if they're executed at the right location in the code, the *outcome* of running the instructions will be the same.